# symfony2 baseUrl not working with IIS in prod

Tags: php, symfony, mod-rewrite, iis, iis-7

I installed symfony2 framework on an IIS server.

When I type `http://localhost/myAlias/app_dev.php`, it works fine, my routing is sending me on `http://localhost/myAlias/app_dev.php`.

When I type `http://localhost/myAlias` implicitly app.php, I receive ***No route found for "GET /myAlias"*** and all my dependencies files (css/js), point to `http://localhost/bundles/file.js`

It looks like Symfony2 is getting the base Url wrong, without the /myAlias in it. But I read somewhere IIS works fine without the equivalent of Rewritebase /myAlias for Apache

My IIS web.config

```
<system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <add value="app.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="call app.php" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="app.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Did I forget to check a box ?

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried clearing the cache in the prod environment? Try the following command:

**Symfony 2.8-**

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

**Symfony 3.0 +**

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```